# How to update multiple mysql rows from a form field

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i am creating a form where i can update multiple rows in my database

first of all i have a form with a field name "pol", this should carry multiple values as declared below using "[]"

```
 <form action="snooze.php" name="frm" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="pol[]" value="<?php echo $row_cert['Policy_Number']; ?>">

</form>
```

This multiple values, i have been able to display using a for each loop

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['pol'])) 
{
    $hobby = $_POST['pol'];


   foreach ($hobby as $hobys=>$value) {
           echo "".$value."<br /><br />";
        }
}
?>
```

but now i am trying to use this multiple values passed in the for each loop in a where clause to update multiple rows in my database, but it only passes 1 value instead of multiple values as the above code does when echo.

this is what i have tried

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['pol'])) 
{
$db = new mysqli('localhost', '---', '----', '----');
if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connect Error: " .$db->connect_error); //TODO: better error handling
}
 $hobby = $_POST['pol'];
 foreach ($hobby as $hobys=>$value) {
$sql = "UPDATE check_niid
           SET niid_status = 'Successful'
         WHERE Policy_Number = '$hobby[$hobys]'";
}
if (!$db->query($sql)) {
    die("Update failed. Error: " .$db->error); //TODO: better error handling
}
}
?>
```

please what could i be doing wrong here, my aim is to be able to update multiple rows using the where clause

Comment: it should be inside the foreach loop if (!$db->query($sql)) {
    die("Update failed. Error: " .$db->error); //TODO: better error handling
}

Comment: thanks so much, i missed that

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it with green tick its useful to future users @Tee

Comment: sure i will, it has a time limit to b able to do dat, trust me

Comment: hold in 3 mins it will let me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query execution is in out side the foreach so . $sql variable overwrite by multiple times and final array value only set in $sql . that only executed once in your query so .it should be inside the foreach loop

```
foreach ($hobby as $hobys=>$value) {
$sql = "UPDATE check_niid
       SET niid_status = 'Successful'
     WHERE Policy_Number = '$hobby[$hobys]'";

 if (!$db->query($sql)) {
die("Update failed. Error: " .$db->error); //TODO: better error handling
    }
 }
```